# docker command not found when executed over bitbucket ssh pipeline

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using bitbucket pipeline to deploy my laravel application, when I push to my repo it start to build and it works perfectly until the docker exec command which will send inline command to execute inside the php container, I get the error

```sh
bash: line 3: docker: command not found
```

which is very wired because when I run the command directly on the same server at the same directory it works perfectly, docker is installed on the server and as you can see inside execute.sh docker-compose works with no issues however when running over the pipeline I get the error, notice the pwd to make sure the command executed in the right directory.

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: php:7.3

pipelines:
  branches:
    testing:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Testing
          deployment: Testing
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip openssh-client
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - composer require phpunit/phpunit
            - vendor/bin/phpunit laravel/tests/Unit
            - ssh do.server.net 'bash -s' < execute.sh
```

Inside execute.sh it looks like this :

```sh
cd /home/docker/docker-laravel
docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d
pwd
docker exec -ti php sh -c "php helpershell.php"
exit
```

And the output from bitbucket pipeline build result looks like this :

```
Successfully built 1218483bd067
Successfully tagged docker-laravel_php:latest
Building nginx
Step 1/1 : FROM nginx:latest
 ---> 4733136e5c3c
Successfully built 4733136e5c3c
Successfully tagged docker-laravel_nginx:latest
Creating php ... 
Creating mysql ... 
Creating mysql ... done
Creating php   ... done
Creating nginx ... 
Creating nginx ... done
/home/docker/docker-laravel
bash: line 3: docker: command not found
```

Comment: Asem did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that part of the reason this is happening is because `docker-compose` and `docker` are two separate commands. Just because one works does not mean they both work. Also you might want to check the indentation of your `bitbucket-pipelines.yaml` file because yaml can be pretty finicky.

See here for sample structure: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html

Comment: As i mentioned above docker is installed and working when I execute the command on the server by myself so it's not a docker being installed issue, as for the indentation, the pipeline works pretty well otherwise it wouldn't execute the script in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining `docker` as a service in the bitbucket pipeline, according to the [documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/databases-and-service-containers/), with a top level `definitions` entry? Like so:

```
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 512  # reduce memory for docker-in-docker from 1GB to 512MB
```

Alternatively `docker` is included and ready to use directly in the image the pipeline is running, then you might try removing the `service` key from your step as that could be conflicting with the `docker` installed on the image (and since you haven't instantiated the docker service via the top level `definitions` entry I've posted above, the pipeline may end up in a state where it thinks docker isn't setup.